# How do I know when a Bluetooth device connects/disconnects to a specific device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Can I detect in my app whether or not the iPhone connected to a specific Bluetooth device? In this case I want to detect whether the phone is connected to my car via Ford SYNC.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

I was already looking into the Core Bluetooth framework but that appears to be just about iBeacons and Bluetooth LE stuff.

Comment: It is possible, the people at Lifetime gyms did it for when you walk into their gyms for recording data.  I saw a presentation on it also at a meetup.

Comment: @php_purest Are you sure that was Bluetooth? Apparently that was the original intent of NFC, which is similar to Bluetooth, but not the same.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I saw they had an entire room of people working out hooked up to the system wirelessly.  I think it was bluetooth, or something very similar.